# Jest, Enzyme and Styled Component not working with Warning: React.createElement

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, enzyme, styled-components

I have created a styled components in a sperate file with the same name and `.css.jsx` for example `Abc.jsx` have `Abc.css.jsx` and it's imported to the `Abc.jsx` to use. But when I try to test `Abc.jsx` I get the below error from the Enzyme mount,

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Seems like React can't locate the styles written in my `Abc.css.jsx`. Does anyone know the reason for this and how to fix this?

**Abc.jsx**

```
import * as Styled from './Abc.css';

function Abc() {
  return (<Styled.Title>ABC</ Styled.Title>);
}

export default Abc
```

**Abc.css.jsx**

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Title = styled.div`
`;
```

**Abc.test.js**

```
import Abc from '../../../components/Abc';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe("My Abc tests", () => {

    let wrapper;

    beforeAll(() => {
        wrapper = mount(<Abc />);
    })

    test("check api call", async () => {
        

    })

});
```

**jest.config**

```
module.exports = {
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/.next/", "<rootDir>/node_modules/"],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setupTests.js"],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy" 
    },
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
        "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
};
```

[image]

[image]

[image: Folder structure]

[image: package.json]

[image: package.json]

Comment: Please give a [mre] rather than just describing it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I have added a reproducible sample

Comment: _"you might have mixed up default and named imports"_

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm sorry I didn't get your answer. Can you please elaborate a little bit more. I'm new to React and all of these technologies. Right now my code works fine and only the test is failing with the above error

Comment: You just _changed_ the import, so which one are you actually using when you get that error? The syntax doesn't look quite right, please give an example you've verified reproduces the problem, and give the exact matching error message.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry. Yes, I have changed it. The current question is the correct one. I have updated the question with the screenshot of the error that I'm getting.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't match the example, which still has a syntax problem. I'm therefore not confident that it does reproduce the error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please tell me the syntax error that you see. That might be the issue

Comment: Please _run the example_ so you can give a coherent [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, Yes, there was a syntax error I have missed the closing tag <Styled.Title>. Now, this gives the exact error.

Comment: But the full error is still a _screenshot_, and one that _doesn't_ match what's in the post.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, I have updated that as well.

Comment: I just created an example in [codesendbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-dhawan-mq2rm), and it is working.

Can you share the structure of folders you have

Comment: @pavlovic265 I have added the folder structure of mine. Also, I forgot to mention that I'm using Next.js as well. I thought that will not make any change.

Comment: I created new  example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-http-ng3b0) with Next.js and it is working.

One difference that i have is importing of `Abc` component. You go three step back and I go one step as tests are on a root lvl.


Can you share `package.json` dependencies versions?

Comment: @pavlovic265 I have added the package.json file screenshots as well. Please check. I think you are using React 16 and in mine, I'm using 17 and the enzyme adapter is different (@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17). Thanks

Comment: @janitheshan can you share `jest.config` file? I added the right dependencies and the test is still passing.

Can you copy a command you use to run tests?

Comment: @pavlovic265 Added the jest.config as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to get the same error as you! in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-http-ng3b0?file=/jest.config.js)

So the issue is in the naming of styled-component files. You name them `[something].css.jsx`.

And in you jest.config file tries to map them as classes or something like that, I assume it is because of the import as it ends with '.css'

```
...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
...
```

There are a couple of things you can do here.

1. Change naming convention for styled-components. From`[something].css.jsx` to `[something].styled.jsx`.
2. Remove `moduleNameMapper`
3. Remove `css` from `moduleNameMapper`

My personal favorite is option 1.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was the issue, or else if I import like [something].css.jsx then also it works

Comment: But I think as you said the option 1 is good.